# What .net class to inherit from to use asp.net sessions, but isn't a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, session, inheritance

I have a asp.net webapplication in vb.net. Sessions are available on a page that inherits from `Inherits System.Web.UI.Page`. To have better separation of concerns I'm thinking about creating a class that knows about server sessions, but isn't a page. I could instance the class with a session-object or set a property, but i was wondering if is it possible to create a class that knows about the session. What should the class inherit from?

What would be a different design pattern?

Comment: To reference the sesssion, just import the namespace: System.Web.SessionState then you can use it in any class.

Comment: Maybe you mean custom session state provider? Please take a look at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.85).aspx especially customProvider property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just access your session with:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

Any class you create as base class can have a property with returns the HttpContext.Session, it is not bound to your Page object.

[HttpContext MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: You missed the `.Current`